# RDLC -Multiple Pages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have built a rdlc report to print one page on A4 size, I usually print one invoice

and that works great, I just want to achieve printing many invoices for the same report

any suggested ideas here is the code which I am using to generate the report viewer

```cs
   SqlDataAdapter sda_rep = new SqlDataAdapter(insertedrecord, sqlcon);
   Dotted_TruckFormViewer frm = new Dotted_TruckFormViewer();  
   ReportParameterCollection rep = new ReportParameterCollection();
   rep.Add(new ReportParameter("ReportParameter1", Program.Current_Year));
   rep.Add(new ReportParameter("ReportParameter2", permeter_print2));
   rep.Add(new ReportParameter("ReportParameter3", permeter_print3));
   rep.Add(new ReportParameter("ReportParameter4", permeter_print4));
   
   frm.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(rep);
   sda_rep.Fill(frm.Insurance_DBDataSet.Truck_Insurance);
   frm.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Thank you

Comment: fill the datasource with many invoices .. add list control and move all your details controls into the list then group the list with invoice number field

Comment: Thank you very much , it is what I wanted exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. fill the datasource with many invoices data
2. add list control and move all your details controls into the list
3. group the list with invoice number field